# Effect of plumbing a surface on the marked length spectrum

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

First I'll recall the plumbing procedure.

Let $M$ be a noded Riemann surface with nodes $p_1,\dots, p_n$. There is a family of pairwise disjoint neighbourhoods of each node $U_i$ that has coordinates holomorphic $z_i,w_i$ so that $U_i\cap M-\{\textrm{nodes}\}$ identifies biholomorphically with $$\{z_i,w_i\in \mathbb{C}^2: 0<|z_i|,|w_i|<\epsilon, z_iw_i=0\}$$ For an $n$-tuple $(t_1,\dots, t_n)\in (0,\infty)^n$ there is a way to replace each $U_i$ by a neighbourhood $U_i^{t_i}$ of the form $$\{z_i,w_i\in \mathbb{C}^2: t_i/\epsilon <|z_i|,|w_i|<\epsilon, z_iw_i=t_i\}$$

Effectively, this replaces each node in the surface with a small cylinder. If $M$ had no punctures, the result of the plumbing would be a compact surface.

My question: what is the effect of the plumbing on the marked length spectrum? Is it naive to think that the length of any curve that lies outside all the $U_i$ does not change? Wolpert, Wolf, and others give expressions for the new metric in $N_i$, and one can thus find information about curves that in the original surface lay in $U_i$. The real thing I am worrying about are curves that intersect $U_i$ and the complement.

This does seem like quite the non-trivial question, so I'm really posting here to ask if this question has been answered before, and if so is there a source.